# Declaring array of values to a struct or a pointer

Tags: c, declaration

I have what appears to be an infuriatingly simple problem.  I have calculated a window function (a long 1-D array of numbers) using Matlab and would like to declare this to a variable array via a simple string.  Problem is, the nature of the program seems to only let me declare it to a pointer to a single float one at a time.

So this code should tell you what I'm trying to do:

```
*(thiz->window) = (5.23304323663142e-06, 7.40064073869153e-06, 9.43199757915201e-06, 1.14014590196513e-05)
```

(the actual arrays are anything from 512 to 8192 elements long)

This compiles correctly but would not assign anything other than the first number to the first address.

I have tried a number of other things but each is more desperate and random than the last so I will leave them out.

What I want is for the second number to go to `*(thiz-\>window+1)`, third number to  `*(thiz-\>window+2)`, ...

Comment: looks like you'll need to use [`memcpy`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html) or something, you can't assign an array, if that's what you're trying to do. What's this about strings? A [mre] would be most helpful .. what is `thiz->window` for instance?

Comment: Recommended: [Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/initialization), [Array initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization) and [Struct and union initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization). Other than that, as already mentioned before, [malloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) and/or [memcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) could be of use for you as well.

Comment: Think I'm understanding better on subsequent readthrus ... If `thiz->window` is a `float[]` then you can initialize it with an initializer list like `float[] window = {34.4, 235.4, ...};`, but if it's part of a `struct` as it looks, you'd have to initialize the whole structure at once I believe. If `thiz->window` is a `float*`, you simply can't assign as you have. If you've got these "hardcoded" numbers you want to assign, probably best IMO to have Matlab dump them to file, and then your C code can read in that file. Or maybe Matlab can generate C source?

Comment: One other thing you should try is read a good C textbook. C is a very unforgiving language and it is not advised to program in it by trial and error.

Comment: you mean "assign" not "declare"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is:

```
static const double MyNumbers[] = { 5.23304323663142e-06, 7.40064073869153e-06, 9.43199757915201e-06, 1.14014590196513e-05 };
memcpy(thiz->window, MyNumbers, sizeof MyNumbers);
```

This requires that `thiz->window` already point to sufficient space (if it is a pointer) or be an array of sufficient size (if it is an array).

If it is a pointer and it is satisfactory to point to the `MyNumbers` array, you can use `thiz->window = MyNumbers;`. You may need to add `const` in the declaration of the `window` member or remove it from `MyNumbers`, depending on circumstances.

If it is a pointer and pointing to `MyNumbers` is not satisfactory, insert:

```
thiz->window = malloc(sizeof MyNumbers);
if (!thiz->window)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error, unable to allocate memory for window coefficients.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

`memcpy` is declared in `<string.h>`; if your program does not already have `#include <string.h>`, insert that.

`malloc` is declared in `<stdlib.h>`; if your program does not already have `#include <stdlib.h>`, insert that.

Answer (score 1):

To copy an array you need smth like this:

```
float myArr[] = {5.23304323663142e-06, 7.40064073869153e-06, 9.43199757915201e-06, 1.14014590196513e-05};

float window[20];

int size = sizeof(myArr)/sizeof(myArr[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    window[i] = myArr[i];
}
```

Note how my `window` is initialized to be big enough to hold the data. This is where you substiute your `thiz->window`, and that's something you need to make sure.

If `thiz->window` is null, you need to allocate it - using function appropriate to your environment. I wouldn't assume that `malloc` is ok. Google says there's something called `mxMalloc`, which suggests there is more than 1 way to allocate memory in Matlab and you need to find out which one to use.

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution I have now, aside from using memcpy for the copying.

Do I need to destroy the myArr[] after the copying or would variables declared inside a function be automatically destroyed afterwards?

Comment: @user25849 No, you don't need to destroy it. The rule is "a `free` for every `malloc`" and there's no `malloc` here.